# Input search getting blocked in JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, browser, internet-explorer-11

I am using IE11 and I have a search box input as follows,

```
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="ctrl.searchText" data-ng-keyup="ctrl.globalSearch()">
```

JS:

```
         function globalSearch() {
            if (_globalSearchConfig.searchText.length > 2) {
                $timeout.cancel(_globalSearchConfig.searchCanceller);
                _globalSearchConfig.searchCanceller = $timeout(_startGlobalSearch, 2000);
            }
        }


       function _startGlobalSearch() {
            _globalSearchConfig.results = []; //Clearing previous search results
            _globalSearchConfig.noResultsToDisplay = false;

            angular.forEach(_filters, function (filter) {
                angular.forEach(filter.ddlItems, function (ddlItem) {
                    if (ddlItem[filter.propertyOfListItem].toUpperCase().indexOf(_globalSearchConfig.searchText.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
                        var result = {};

                        angular.copy(ddlItem, result);
                        _globalSearchConfig.results.push(new GlobalSearchResult(result, filter));
                    }
                });
            });

            if (_globalSearchConfig.results.length === 0) {
                _globalSearchConfig.noResultsToDisplay = true;
            }
        }
```

Here filter.ddlItems has 2659 overall.

The flow...,

When I search for 'manager' ,I am getting the search results, then

When I clear manager and type trying to type something it got locked and able to enter atleast one word and then browser showing a popup "Not responding due to long running script".

Can anyone please suggest help.Thanks.

Comment: when you delete at some point you are searching for the empty string, that's probably why it hangs. Try to not search if the value in searchText is an empty string

Comment: Hi  @FrancescoDiStefano, I ket a condition for length check   if (_globalSearchConfig.searchText.length > 2) {

Comment: yes, but there is a 2 second timeout in between your check and whatever happens to searchText

Comment: Ohk in that case I would cancel timeout incase the searchText length is < 2.

Comment: Have you used F12 dev tools to check if there's any error in console on IE 11? You could also try to add breakpoints using F12 dev tools to debug the code. Does this issue only happen on IE or also happen on other browsers? Besides, could you provide a minimal sample to reproduce the issue? It seems nothing happening when running only the above code.